# Cannot ignore directory using zip

Tags: zip

I have this command:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -eo pipefail
cd "$(dirname "$(dirname "$BASH_SOURCE")")"

zip -9 -r zips/function.zip . \
 -x '*.git*' -x '*.idea*' -x '*.idea*' \
 -x */node_modules/typescript/*  \
 -x */zips/* -x '*.zip' -x */node_modules/puppeteer/*
```

and for some reason I get this in the output:

```
updating: node_modules/typescript/loc/lcl/PTB/Targets/ (stored 0%)
updating: node_modules/typescript/loc/lcl/PTB/Targets/ProjectItemsSchema.xaml.lcl (deflated 63%)
updating: node_modules/typescript/loc/lcl/PTB/Targets/TypeScriptProjectProperties.xaml.lcl (deflated 90%)
updating: node_modules/typescript/loc/lcl/PTB/Targets/TypeScriptCompile.xaml.lcl (deflated 86%)
```

so I guess that

```
*/node_modules/typescript/*
```

does not ignore:

```
node_modules/typescript
```

?

Comment: Is there any subtle reason why you're quoting only _some_ of the `-x` exclude patterns?

Comment: cause `'*/foo/*'` mean something different than `*/foo/*` my G, but as such perhaps your question is getting at the nature of the question in the OP